# Coffee theorem puzzle

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, alphametic

I am back yet with another puzzle, my last one was made this morning, and this one is a copied one from an app/website called Brilliant. So, this is especially for those who do not have Brilliant available for them.

There is a multiplication where COFFEE× 3= THEOREM. What is H, if every letter corresponds to a different digit?
Note: T is not equal to 0.

Comment: Hello @Anonymous. Please note that there are many Alphametic Solver tools available on the net. One can also program to solve these. So my suggestion is to add a no-computer tag to these in future.

Comment: @DrD I have fixed my mistake. I would love more advice like this so I can be a better puzzle maker, since I AM new

Comment: @Anonymous25. No problem. It really depends on what TYPE of puzzles you are interested in designing. There are many catagories - see the tags. In my experience this site is quite advanced in terms of  puzzle solving. Brilliant talented puzzle solvers here. I myself truly like to challenge them. If you like - and are good at- a certain catagory, let me know then I will offer specific suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

klabuster has got the answer but here is how you would approach it using logic

> The first thing that stands out is the last two digits.
>  In particular, we have that $EE \times 3 \equiv EM \mod 100$.
>  Now, we shall assume that different letters correspond to different digits (otherwise, there are a bunch of solutions) so that, for example, we have $E \neq 0$ because that would force $M = 0$.
>  We can look at the other $9$ two digit cases for $EE$ to check which ones can possibly satisfy the modular equation above.
>  For $E=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ the residues of $EE \times 3 \mod 100$ are $33,66,99,32,65,98,31,64,97$, respectively, and we see that only in the case $E=9$ does the tens part of the residue match $E$, that is $E=9$ and $M=7$.
>  Analyzing the next two digits we must have that $FF \times 3 + 2\equiv OR \mod 100$. (Note the $2$ is carried over from the $EE\times 3$ product).
>  Additionally, we enforce that no two of $F, O$ or $R$ can be the same and that none of them can be either $7$ or $9$ ($M,E$). Analysing the above residues once more (with the additional $2$) we find that the only possibilities for $(F,O,R)$ that work are $(1,3,5)$, $(2,6,8)$ and $(3,0,1)$.
>  Moving up to the $10000$s place in the product we find that either we must have $O \times 3 \equiv E = 9 \mod 10$ (when $F=1$ or $F=2$) or
>  $O \times 3 + 1 \equiv E = 9\mod 10$ (when $F=3$).
>  Immediately, we see that the $F=2,3$ cases do not work and that the only case that does is $O=3$, that is $F=1$ and $R=5$.
>  Finally, looking at the $100000$s place in the product, we see that we must have $C \times 3 = TH$ and that no two of these numbers may be the same and none of them may fall in the set of digits already used, i.e, $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$.
>  Looking at the cases $C=2,4,6,8,0$ we obtain products $TH$ with values $06,12,18,24,00$ and clearly, only the case $(C,T,H) = (8,2,4)$ satisfies our constraints (with $T\neq 0$) so that, overall, we have $$ 831199 \times 3 = 2493597 $$ and $H=4$.
>  **NB** If we do not enforce $T \neq 0$, there would be only one other solution $231199 = 0693597$.

Comment: Wow, I have attracted @hexomino, I love your puzzles

Comment: @Anonymus25 Thanks, I do like to check whether these puzzles can be done just with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

H is

> 4

Because

> 831199 x 3 = 2493597

Comment: Wow! I did not expect an answer that fast. Anyways, it is correct, so you are getting that precious tick ;)

Comment: Well, I just used some tool to brutforce it :( [see here](https://www.dcode.fr/cryptarithm-solver). Creating the puzzle was probably way harder.

Comment: Just so you know, 1) I didn't create the puzzle, the website Brilliant.org did. 2)  Isn't it considered cheating by using google? I am erasing the tick.

Comment: Just kidding, I guess it's fine